# Spring Boot - MockMVC test not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit4, mockmvc

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/deviceevent")
public class DeviceEventController {

    @RequestMapping(value={ "/list"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
    public String deviceeventList()  {

        return "tdk/deviceEvent/DeviceEventList";
    }
}
```

and this other test class. Tests using Spring's MockMVC framework. This drives an MVC application in a test, as if it was running in a container,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MockMvcTests {

    // Pull in the application context created by @ContextConfiguration
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Setup MockMVC to use our Spring Configuration
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void getDeviceEventsTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/deviceevent/list") //
                        .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()) //
                .andExpect(model().size(1)) //
    }
```

But I got this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.tdk.iot.web.controllers.MockMvcTests.getDeviceEventsTest(MockMvcTests.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Your test doesn't look like a typical Spring Boot-based test. I'd expect to see `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest`.  What version of Boot are you using?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson  WebMvcTest was the part missing !.     , please convert to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(WarehouseController.class)
public class WarehosueControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @MockBean
    WarehouseService warehouseService;//the business service



    @Test
    public void testGetWarehouses() throws Exception{
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1L);

        WarehouseDTO warehouseDTO = new WarehouseDTO();
        List<WarehouseDTO> warehouseDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        warehouseDTO.setId(1L);
        warehouseDTO.setCode("test_code");
        warehouseDTO.setName("test_name");
        warehouseDTO.setAddress("adress value");
        warehouseDTOs.add(warehouseDTO);
        given(this.warehouseService.getWarehouses(0, list))
                .willReturn(warehouseDTOs);

        this.mvc.perform(get("/api/warehouses?filterType=0&ids=1")
                .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))

                //check if the jason node exsits
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorCode").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].name").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].code").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].id").exists())

                //check the type of json node
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorCode").isString())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].name").isString())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].code").isString())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].id").isNumber())

                //check the return value
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorCode").value(""))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].name").value("test_name"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].code").value("test_code"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].address").value("adress value"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload[0].id").value(1));
    }
}
```